# Grails BootStrap: No signature of method: *.addTo* applicable

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes: User

```
class User {

    String username
    String password
    String email
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

//  static belongsTo = [profile: Profile]

    static constraints = {
        username size: 3..20, unique: true, nullable: false, validator: { _username ->
            _username.toLowerCase() == _username
        }
        password size: 6..100, nullable: false, validator: { _password, user ->
            _password != user.username
        }
        email email: true, blank: false
//      profile nullable: true
    }
}
```

and Profile:

```
class Profile {

    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    byte[] photo
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = [User]

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false
        middleName nullable: true
        lastName blank: false
        photo nullable: true, maxSize: 2 * 1024**2
    }
}
```

A profile can belong to only one user and a user can have (or belong to?) only one profile. When I try to create the objects in `BootStrap.groovy` in the current setup I get an error saying that the `addTo()` method does not exist. I don't really know what I am doing wrong. This is how I am creating them in `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
User arun = new User(username: 'arun', password: 'password', email: 'arun@email.com').save(failOnError: true)
Profile arunProfile = new Profile(firstName: 'Arun', lastName: 'Allamsetty').addToUser(arun).save(failOnError: true)
```

Can someone please point out the mistake(s). I am sure it's silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strict bi-directional one-one relationship is required as you have requested for:

*A profile can belong to only one user and a user can have (or belong to?) only one profile*

Three modifications are mainly required in domain classes:

```
//User.groovy
static hasOne = [profile: Profile]

static constraints = { 
    profile unique: true
}

//Profile.groovy
User user
```

Above is a bi-directianl one-one relationship. You do not need `addTo*` anymore while creating each of them.

```
Profile arunProfile = new Profile(firstName: 'Arun', lastName: 'Allamsetty')

User arun = new User(username: 'arun', password: 'password', 
                     email: 'arun@email.com', 
                     profile: arunProfile).save()
```