# one to one relationship between domains

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to Grails , i want to do one to one relationship between 2 domains for instance Author and book , so the Author has only one book  and for sure the book has one Author , i used **static belongsTo** in the book domain , but in the CRUD views specially in the **CREATE** view for the Author, it shows me a list with all the created books, i don't want that , i want to show me **"Add book"** if there is no books found or gets me the associated book for that author  .

thanks

Comment: Okay, well the scaffolded views are what you get for free. They're designed to get the basic structure down for your CRUD interface. You can restructure the page to behave how you want, burt there's no way for you to demand that Grails scaffolds views differently.

Comment: So all my relationship setting in the domains are right ? by adding **belongsTo** in the book domain and nothing in the author domains,  this also supports the cascade deleting ? so i have to do **Add book** feature in the controller , am i right ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Could you provide a screenshot of what you see, versus a mock up of what you would like to see?

What makes you think Grails can generate what you would like to see?

Comment: Ok ,i have 2 domains Author and Book , the relationship between them one to one  , so to make this relationship i added **belongsTo** in the book domain , and added an object for the book domain in the author domain , first of all is that  right to define a cascaded one to one relationship ? Second , as you see in the **Create** view [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3Ebt65IDJhWdjJuZVkyUEEtcm8&usp=sharing) ,i want rather the drop down menu i want to get me the associated  book for the Author and if there is no book it gives me **Add book**, is it clear now ?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26351483/2051952) would help.